# Executar uma procedure a partir de uma aplicacão Java

Tags: java, oracle

Tenho uma procedure dentro do  banco oracle, porém gostaria de executa-la a partir de uma aplicação java desktop que estou desenvolvendo.
Como faço para executar uma procedure oracle com parametros em java?

Comment: Você já tentou ver se o connector do Oracle não possui a opção de executar procedures?

Comment: Ainda não, pois tenho pouco conhecimento em programação.

Comment: André, você ainda não tentou nada? Você quer algum tipo de tutorial? Sua pergunta está um pouco ampla. Executar procedures é algo muito comum em Java e faz parte do padrão JDBC.

Answer (score 3):

Os comandos de banco de dados que deseja utilizar em sua aplicação java devem ser feitos via "Connector JDBC", que uma biblioteca que facilita, e muito, a conexão com o banco de dados que necessita.

No seu caso, pode baixar o do Oracle aqui: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Não sei qual a IDE está utilizando, mas caso seja java recomendo ler este artigo:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db_pt_BR.html

Conforme a própria Oracle, você pode usar o connector para fazer procedure:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_jdbc.htm

A respeito da dúvida especifica, de uma olhada como iniciar uma conexão com o connector e após isso este código ira te auxiliar a resolver o problema. (Código do link que citei acima).

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import oracle.jdbc.*;

public class EmpSearch
{

  public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException
  {
   // check whether there are two command-line arguments before proceeding
   if ( args.length < 2)
    {
     System.out.println("Enter both a first and last name as command-line arguments.");
     System.out.println("You can enter a complete name or an initial substring.");
     System.out.println("For example: java EmpSearch j doe");
     }
   else
     {
      // connect to a local XE database as user HR
      OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
      ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521/XE");
      Connection conn = ods.getConnection();

      // call the PL/SQL procedures with the three parameters
      // the first two string parameters (1 and 2) are passed to the procedure
      // as command-line arguments
      // the REF CURSOR parameter (3) is returned from the procedure
      String jobquery = "begin get_emp_info(?, ?, ?); end;";
      CallableStatement callStmt = conn.prepareCall(jobquery);
      callStmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
      callStmt.setString(1, args[0]);
      callStmt.setString(2, args[1]);
      callStmt.execute();

      // return the result set
      ResultSet rset = (ResultSet)callStmt.getObject(3);

      // determine the number of columns in each row of the result set
      ResultSetMetaData rsetMeta = rset.getMetaData();
      int count = rsetMeta.getColumnCount();

      // print the results, all the columns in each row
      while (rset.next()) {
          String rsetRow = "";
          for (int i=1; i<=count; i++){
                 rsetRow = rsetRow + " " + rset.getString(i);
          }
          System.out.println(rsetRow);
       }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Uma outra forma de se ter o mesmo resultado é usando a classe `SimpleJdbcCall`:**

```
          SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource())).withCatalogName("Owner"."PackageName").withFuctionName("Store Procedure Name");
          SqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource()
          .addValue("attribute1", attribute1.getId())
          .addValue("attribute2", Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()));

         Long executionId = call.executeFunction(BigDecimal.class, paramMap).longValue();
```

Comment: Você está no **stackoverflow em português**. Sugiro que traduza sua resposta.

Comment: Desculpa pessoal, havia respondido a mesma coisa em outro fórum... Não acontecerá novamente. Abraço;